# Adding column in data-import.xml doesn't affected in solr search

Tags: solr

I have added a new column in my data-import.xml file. When i search query through solr, the column is not getting searched.

I have tried importing data 2-3 times but its not happening

Comment: Importing and searching are two different things. Do you see the data present in the document when querying for it in Solr?

Comment: Did you modified the schema file and re-indexed the data?

Comment: @MatsLindh yes data is present in database however,  i m not able to search for the column in solr search

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti yes, i modified the schema file adding the column in that

Comment: @RohitRaghav:Could you please check same through solr admin page if you see all your fields for the default query

Comment: @RohitRaghav I'm not talking about the database. It the data present in _the document in Solr_? It's important to decide whether the data actually has been imported and is not being found, or if it's not being imported at all. You're going to have to add the query you're using and an example of the document in Solr as well to your question.

Comment: after reloading the core and importing again, it is showing the data in search query. Thanks for all your inputs